# Same value is getting displayed on Left and Right Hand Side of SysListPanel Form Ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have used SysListPanel to display a form where we will have left panel and right panel. Whenever we double click on Right hand panel record it moves to left hand side and that value wont appear in right hand side. But I got an issue here. When I double click on RHS(right hand side) record it moved to LHS. I closed form and Opened it. I can be able to see same record in both LHS and RHS. Can someone please let me know how can I remove the value form RHS once its moved to LHS.

Also I would like to know where its getting decided to store RecId or Id in the relation table(table where data is stored when we move to LHS).?
Example of form UI I am talking about is in SysAdmin-UserGroups-UsersTab

Below is code in init of form
public void init()
{

```
#resAppl
#define.BPTeamName('Testdata')
;

callerRecord =  element.args().record();

if(callerRecord.TableId == tableNum(CustTable))
{

    select BPTeamMembCriterion where BPTeamMembCriterion.Name == #BPTeamName;

    sysListPanel = SysListPanelRelationTable::newForm(element,
                         element.controlId(formControlStr(TableAlpha, ListPanelTabPage)),
                         'Selected text', 'Available text',#ImageUserGroup,
                         tableNum(TableAlpha),
                         fieldNum(TableAlpha, BPTeam),
                         fieldNum(TableAlpha, CustAccount),
                         tableNum(BPTeam),
                         fieldNum(BPTeam, RecId),
                         [fieldNum(BPTeam, Name),fieldNum(BPTeam, Description)],
                         fieldNum(BPTeam, TeamMemberCriterion),
                         BPTeamMembershipCriterion.RecId,
                         identifierStr(Validate),0,true,true);

}
super();
sysListPanel.init();

sysListPanel.parmRelationRangeValue(queryValue(callerRecord.RecId));
sysListPanel.fill();
```

}

TableAlpha
Fields:
Field1: BPteam
Field2 : CustAccount
Both above fields stores Recids

Comment: Please share code example

Comment: What is your source code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] on how to phrase a question with the best chances to receive an answer here.

Comment: Added Code @Matej  & RamenChef

Comment: Are `fieldNum(TableAlpha, BPTeam)` and `fieldNum(BPTeam, RecId)` related? Try deleting everything after ` [fieldNum(BPTeam, Name),fieldNum(BPTeam, Description)]`. The expected argument `dateRangeField` you have `fieldNum(BPTeam, TeamMemberCriterion)`. It sounds like you're not passing the correct stuff.

Comment: Yes, TableAlpha table field BPteam stores RecId of BpTeamTable. Ok. Will delete stuff after  [fieldNum(BPTeam, Name),fieldNum(BPTeam, Description)] and will test and will update here. Thanks

Comment: If i Comment the stuff after what you said, I am not getting any value on RHS of pane. Its empty. @alexkwitny